# Can I hook into the expiration of a remoting object?

Tags: .net, remoting, .net-remoting, marshalbyrefobject

I have a class which inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`, and in it I am overriding the lifetime service to give it an `InitialLeaseTime` of two hours:

```
public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
{
    // Expire after two hours.
    var lease = (ILease)base.InitializeLifetimeService();
    if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
        lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);

    return lease;
}
```

Now, I want to perform some logic when the lease expires. Is there an event or a hook into the expiration? I have searched Google and MSDN, but I have found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a lease expires the `ISponsor.Renewal` method is being called on the object's sponsor.
Thus, you can implement `ISponsor` yourself and put your logic there.

To do that, you'll need to call the `ILease.Register` method in your implementation of `InitializeLifetimeService`, passing your `ISponsor` as the argument.